# Rounding numbers to the nearest decimal places in R

Tags: r, decimal, rounding

Consider the following data set:

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:10,
                 v1=c(2.35456185,1.44501001,2.98712312,0.12345123,0.96781234,
                      1.23934551,5.00212233,4.34120000,1.23443213,0.00112233),
           v2=c(0.22222222,0.00123456,2.19024869,0.00012000,0.00029848,
                0.12348888,0.46236577,0.85757000,0.05479729,0.00001202))
```

My intention is to round the values in `v1` and `v2` to the nearest one decimal place (10% of observation), two decimals (40% of observations), and three decimal places (50% of observations) **randomly**. I can use the `round()` function to round numbers to certain decimal places uniformly. In my case, however, it's not uniform. Thank you in advance!

Example of output needed (of course mine is not random):

```
id   v1    v2
 1   2.3   0.2
 2   1.45  0
 3   2.99  2.19
 4   0.12  0
 5   0.97  0
 6   1.239 0.123
 7   5.002 0.462
 8   4.341 0.858
 9   1.234 0.055
10   0.001 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may create a grouping with `sample` based on the `prob`bablity, and then `round` the `v1` column based on the value of the group

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(grp = sample(1:3, size = n(), replace = TRUE,
     prob = c(0.10, 0.4, 0.5))) %>% 
  mutate(v1 = round(v1, first(grp))) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 2
      id    v1
   <int> <dbl>
 1     1 2.36 
 2     2 1.44 
 3     3 2.99 
 4     4 0.123
 5     5 0.97 
 6     6 1.24 
 7     7 5.00 
 8     8 4.3  
 9     9 1.23 
10    10 0
```

For multiple columns, use `across` to loop over

```
df %>%
   mutate(across(v1:v2, ~ round(.x, sample(1:3, size = n(),
    replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.10, 0.40, 0.50)))))
```

---

Or we pass the `sample`d output in `digits` argument of `round` directly

```
df$v1 <- with(df, round(v1, sample(1:3, size = nrow(df), 
    replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.10, 0.4, 0.5))))
```

#### Update

Just checking the rounded values

```
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(across(v1:v2, ~ sample(1:3, size = n(),
    replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.10, 0.40, 0.50)), 
    .names = "{.col}_sample_ind"),
    across(v1:v2, ~  round(.x, digits = cur_data()[[str_c(cur_column(),
      "_sample_ind")]]), 
    .names = "{.col}_rounded")) %>%
   as_tibble
```

-output

```
  # A tibble: 10 × 7
      id      v1        v2 v1_sample_ind v2_sample_ind v1_rounded v2_rounded
   <int>   <dbl>     <dbl>         <int>         <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     1 2.35    0.222                 3             2      2.36       0.22 
 2     2 1.45    0.00123               3             3      1.44       0.001
 3     3 2.99    2.19                  1             2      3          2.19 
 4     4 0.123   0.00012               3             2      0.123      0    
 5     5 0.968   0.000298              3             1      0.968      0    
 6     6 1.24    0.123                 3             3      1.24       0.123
 7     7 5.00    0.462                 2             3      5          0.462
 8     8 4.34    0.858                 2             1      4.34       0.9  
 9     9 1.23    0.0548                2             2      1.23       0.05 
10    10 0.00112 0.0000120             2             3      0          0
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. One more question: Is that possible to do the same exercise for two columns (I will add `v2`)?

Comment: All the values of `v1` and `v2` are rounded to three decimal places when using the `across()` function. Could you check it once again? Tnx!

Comment: Hi @akrun! I got an error message which says `Error in select(., id) : unused argument (id)`.

Comment: I think your latest answer (the big table you get) is correct if the trailing zeros are dropped. I mean instead of `1.230` for the nearest two decimal places it's nice if we manage to produce `1.23` only. Txs!

Comment: @iGada just add `as_tibble` as in theupdate

Comment: The original problem comes back when you add `as_tibble`. Sorry for bothering you a lot.

Comment: @iGada please do know that `as_tibble` does some print formatting, but if you extract the column values, it will be your expected output.  If your issue is just to show in printing, then it may need `format` to a character

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try removing the trailing zeros as printing numbers exactly as they are is very important in my case.

Comment: @iGada perhaps you know how R prints a numeric vector `c(0, 0.12, 5.863)
#[1] 0.000 0.120 5.863`, which is basically a print format.  It has nothing to do with the rounding issue you mentioned

Answer (score 3):

Update: Addressing the probabilities:

```
library(dplyr)
    
df %>%
 rowwise() %>% 
 mutate(v2 = round(v1,sample(1:3, 1,  prob = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.5))))
```

```
      id      v1    v2
   <int>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 2.35     2.35
 2     2 1.45     1.44
 3     3 2.99     2.99
 4     4 0.123    0.12
 5     5 0.968    1   
 6     6 1.24     1.24
 7     7 5.00     5.00
 8     8 4.34     4.34
 9     9 1.23     1.2 
10    10 0.00112  0
```

Here we round row wise randomly between 1 and 3:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(V1 = round(v2,sample(1:3, 1)))
```

```
      id      v1    V2
   <int>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 2.35    2.36 
 2     2 1.45    1.44 
 3     3 2.99    2.99 
 4     4 0.123   0.123
 5     5 0.968   0.968
 6     6 1.24    1.24 
 7     7 5.00    5.00 
 8     8 4.34    4.34 
 9     9 1.23    1.23 
10    10 0.00112 0.001
```